# How to pass the rest args of a variadic function to another function?

Tags: clojure, idioms

I want to write a function which simply updates a vector in a map with new value, but can take any number of args, but at least one.

Here is example:

```clj
(defn my-update [what item & items]
  (update what :desired-key conj item items))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Despite that `update` do have a signature with multiple values (like `[m k f x y]`), all remaining arguments to `my-update` will be joined into one sequence, which will be passed to `conj` as one argument.

Instead, wrapping `conj` with `apply` in an anonymous function does work, but looks not so elegant:

```clj
(defn my-update [what item & items]
  (update what :desired-key #(apply conj % item items))
```

What is the idiomatic way of writing such a function like `my-update`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply insert [apply](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply) before `update`. That will call the function `update` with the arguments that follows except for the last argument which should be a sequence, whose elements become the remaining arguments in the call:

```
(defn my-update [what item & items]
  (apply update what :desired-key conj item items))

(my-update {:desired-key [0]} 1 2 3 4)
;; => {:desired-key [0 1 2 3 4]}

(my-update {:desired-key [0]})
;; Exception: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: my-update
```

This way, you can keep the function argument list `[what item & items]` that makes it clear that at least one item needs to be provided.

In general, a call `(apply f a b c ... [x y z ...])` will evaluate to the same as `(f a b c ... x y z ...)`.

Comment: @tosh You can call `(apply f a b c ... [x y z ...])` and it will evaluate to the same as `(f a b c ... x y z ...)` for any choice of function `f`.

Comment: I never would have thought of this trick. I still lean towards introducing a helper function just so you could introduce a descriptive name and avoid too much complexity in a single form.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing solution isn't so bad.  One small improvement is to use the `into` function, which uses `conj` internally to join two sequences together:

```
(defn my-update [what & items]
  (update what :a into items))
```

with result

```
(my-update {:a [1]} 2 3 4) => {:a [1 2 3 4]}
```

---

Another alternative is to extract out the anonymous function into a named function:

```
(defn append-to-seq
  [seq item items]
  (-> (vec seq)  ; ensure it is a vector so conj adds to the end, not beginning
    (conj item)
    (into items)))

(defn my-update [what item & items]
  (update what :a append-to-seq item items))
```